# Get total list items from Sharepoint on another domain using SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, cors, spservices

this is my first post in Stackoverflow. Hope you guys can help me with my problem. I have a HTML page on domain1.sharepoint.com and I'm trying to get the total list items from a SharePoint on domain2.sharepoint.com using JQuery+SPServices.

I understand that due to same-origin policy, I need to use XMLHttpRequest (CORS) to get the data I need. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to put the XMLHttpRequest into SPServices. I've tried, and getting 'undefined' error. I'm pretty new with JavaScript, appreciate all the help.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
$.support.cors = true;
function createCORSRequest(method, refURL) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, refURL, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, refURL);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

function makeCorsRequest() {
  var refURL = 'http://domain1.sharepoint.com';
  var spURL = refURL;

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', spURL);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }
  xhr.onload = function() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        webURL: spURL,
        listName: "Message Log",
        viewName: "{70DFBF9A-5266-4D69-AD01-E848301B51BB}",
        async: false,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Status' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, status) {
            $("#countlist").html($(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").length);
        }
    });
};

  xhr.onerror = function(e, jqxhr) {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request. ' + jqxhr);
  };

  xhr.send();
}

onload = makeCorsRequest;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing too much.  This line:

$.support.cors = true;

Should be the only thing you need in orde to enable cross domain.  This tells jQuery to enable cors an it takes care of the rest.

Once this is set, can can call SPServices the normal way and insuring you set the 'webURL' option to point to the domain2.

Note that although this will work in 'modern' browsers, IE (I think) will prompt the user for permission.